# Typescript passing optional param to function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function

I have a request function that can accept a param for filtering, or not (it is optional). I can pass something to my func like this

```
myFunc({id: 123})
```

and then inside my func I have this constructor:

```
const myFunc = async ({ id }: { id?: string }) => {
  const filters = {
    ...(id && { movie_id: id })
  };
  // there is use for filters later
}
```

as you can see the `id` is optional but I can't send empty param fields.

such as:

```
myFunc(); //doesn't work
myFunc({}); //works
```

is there a way to make this work for when I call `myFunc()` without anything inside the brackets and still have an optional param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could type your param:

```
type MyFuncProps = {
  id?:number
}

const myFunc = async (prop?: MyFuncProps) => { ... }
```

This way, the argument is optional

Or, if you don't want to type your parameters, you can use a default value like this:

```
const myFunc = async ({ id }: { id?: string } = {}) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
interface ImyFunProps = {
  id?:number
}

const myFunc = async (prop?: ImyFunProps) => { 
  const {id} = props;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous answer, but you have to handle undefined props:

```
  async function myFunc(prop?: {id?: string}){ 


    const filters = prop && Object.keys(prop).length? { movie_id: prop.id }: {};

  // there is use for filters later
  
}

myFunc(); //works
myFunc({}); //works
myFunc({id: 'abc'}); //works
```

Comment: I need `myFunc()` to work

Comment: the question is what you want to do in myFunc() when you have no id. you cant destructure id. so you need another logic inside your function

Comment: I can assign whole params block to empty object as stated in accepted answer. that way I can pass `myFunc()` without any problems and the function itself will do the work for reformatting the filters object. This way I do not have to call empty object every time I do not have a param for this function.

Comment: @denistepp ok i updated the code.